# How does Postman retrieve cookies from the server?

Tags: cookies, postman

I am implementing consuming a REST API.  My development environment is not C#, cURL, PHP, or any other commonly-used environment.  I am using a Postman collection furnished by the API's developers as a base for my implementation.  Issuing the request works:
[Postman screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jeLT.png)

[Automatically added cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A82Zf.png)

When I disable the Cookie Jar, the request no longer works in Postman.

I believe that what I need to do is to imitate whatever Postman is doing to retrieve those cookies and include them in the header of my request.  How is Postman retrieving those server-side cookies?